# Unity Webplayer -- building & publishing

Tags: build, unity-game-engine, unity-web-player

I built my game by clicking `File → Build settings → Web Player → Build`

I, then, copied the folder that I built my game in to my Dropbox folder (i.e. I uploaded both my `HTML` and my `UNITY3D` files in my Dropbox folder).

In the folder I just copied over (the one that is now in my Dropbox) I right-clicked on the generated `HTML` file and clicked on `Share Dropbox link`.

I gave the link to people, but nothing happens when they copy and paste the `URL` in their browser and give permission for the plugin to run...

Have I missed a step somewhere?

Thanks,

Comment: Try to move it to `public` folder and then share a link to `index.html`.

Comment: I did, but as I was figuring out how to enable my Public folder, I discovered that currently only 'Pro' and 'Dropbox for Business' users can enable Public folders, so I would have to upgrade first. I guess I would have to look for free web hosing as my only alternative. Correct?

Comment: Nope. Everyone have Public folder in the root of dropbox. You don't need to do anything with it, cause it's public out of box. Just get shared link of `index.html` file and open it in browser.

Comment: BTW, you can test if it works for everyone using private mode in browser.